# Counting the time when the user is in the discord bot voice channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

It seems to work, but when I exit the voice channel, the time is still counted in the database. now I will edit the question and add my code
_client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += UserConnection;

```
     public static async Task UserConnection(SocketUser arg, SocketVoiceState stat1, SocketVoiceState stat2)
            {
                var user = arg as SocketGuildUser;
    
                var profile = UsrDb.GetUserHours(user.Id, user.Guild.Id);
    
               

            if (profile == null)
            {
                profile = new Usr
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    GuildId = user.Guild.Id
                };
            }

            profile.startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;


            await UsrDb.SetUsr(profile); //recording time in the database

        }

[Command("check user time")]
        public async Task UserTimeCheck()
        {
            var profile = UsrDb.GetUserHours(Context.User.Id, Context.Guild.Id);

            var eb = new EmbedBuilder();

            if (profile == null)
            {
                await ReplyAsync($"{Context.User.Username} your time 0 hours 0 minutes 0 second");
            }

            profile.endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            TimeSpan total = profile.endTime - profile.startTime;

            eb.WithAuthor($"{Context.User.Username} - Your voice time");
            eb.WithDescription($"{total.Hours} hrs | {total.Minutes} min | {total.Seconds} sec.");
            await ReplyAsync(embed: eb.Build());
        }
```

Comment: aren't thre UserJoined/UserLeft events? Store the "begin" timestamp, subtract if from the "end" Timestampt and you have your duration? Why loop endlessly?

Comment: @PatrickArtner There is no UserLeft infinite loop event in the documentation I wrote it so that while the user is in the voice channel seconds are counted if the user leaves the channel the loop stops

Comment: I just don't have any ideas how to do it differently how to count the time while the user is in the voice channel

Comment: You don't need to count the time as time passes (in a loop). Do what @PatrickArtner suggested, simply log the join time and you can determine the duration with simple math (subtraction) `endTime - startTime`.  You could even check how long the user has been in the channel (if they haven't yet left) using `currentTime - startTime`.  Especially if `UsrDb` is an actual database, that a lot of unnecessary database calls, counting seconds in a loop.

Comment: @Anu6is explain your idea in more detail, I didn't understand much

Comment: User joins the voice channel, you log the time in the database. When you execute the command to check how long user has been in the channel all you need to do is read the time you logged (start time) and minus that from the current time.  The same `UserVoiceStateUpdated` event will fire when the user leaves the channel. When that happens you can again, calculate the duration using current time minus the start time you logged. There is no need to start or stop a loop.

Comment: @Anu6is Apparently I understood your idea, thank you tomorrow I will try to implement it because today I am very tired, thank you for paying me your attention

Comment: @Anu6is  startTime should be written as the UtcNow parameter?

Comment: that should be fine, yes

Comment: @Anu6is It seems to work, but when I exit the voice channel, the time is still counted in the database. now I will edit the question and add my code

Comment: @Anu6is in General the UserVoiceStateUpdated method does not stop working when I left the voice channel

Comment: What do u mean the method doesn't stop working? It inserts the profile into the database and it stops. There's nothing left for it to do. You aren't acknowledging anywhere in the code that the user has left the voice channel which is your issue. The method isn't continuously running, it's only run when the event fires. The event fires when the users joins a voice channel **as well as** when the user leaves the voice channel.

Comment: @Anu6is So I don't know what to write when the user left the voice channel

Comment: uhh....are you trying to get the total time spend in a voice channel in a single instance or total time spent in a voice channel over time? For example... I joined a voice channel 3 different times in 5 days and run the command after 7 days should I get the total time spent for the 3 times I joined?

Comment: @Anu6is I'm already confused about everything, please explain to me how to stop the time after the user left the voice channel

Comment: **1** You didn't answer my previous question. **2** There is no time to "stop", as I mentioned before, you set a start time and never acknowledge when the user leaves. **3** It may be better to got to the [dotnet_discord-net](https://discord.gg/discord-api) channel and ask for assistance